# Android: Display digits in Arabic format

Tags: android, arabic

How can I show the digits in Arabic format?
So, if I have integers: **1,2,3** they become **'١', '٢', '٣**'

Comment: Seeing as your profile says that you're from Egypt, I think you might be translating your language's name for digits in the Arabic alphabet incorrectly into English. Those digits are *not* called "Hindi" in English. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz I modified the question's title, as mentioned in your wikipedia article, these numbers are sometimes called "Indian numbers". that's where the confusion came from.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### set the locale to Arabic, Egypt

```
NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("ar","EG"));
nf.format(i);
```

Comment: Is there a way to translate all digits on our ui resources as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 1;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
nf.format(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows the numbers as 1,2,3. nothing changed

Comment: What is your minSdkLevel?

Comment: 17, I found the correct way to do it, check my answer

Comment: can you try new Locale("hi", "IND")

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see your number in persian or arabic format, you must use persian or arabic fonts. With android studio's default font you see them in English format . So do like this: 1. Go to this address File \new \ folder \ assets folder You can create a folder that is named as fonts 2. For your textview or edittext that you want to change it's font should do as this

Typeface face=Typeface.createformatassest (getassest (),"fonts/BZAR.TTF"); Textview.settypeface (face);

Fonts is my folder in assets folder.

If you use persian or arabic fonts your numbers format become to arabic format.